Missing flag "IPC_CREAT" in header file <sys/ipc.h>
While writing a code for creating shared memory, I didn't find IPC_CREAT flag in the header file <sys/ipc.h>...when i open the ipc.h file no flags where defined i,e IPC_CREAT , IPC_PRIVATE and many more flags and structures were missing, but I was able to execute the code (including IPC_CREAT flag) and it was running properly.
When I googled ipc.h file, it consisted of all the flags and structures I needed.
I have already tried updating my header file using sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r). It didn't update any file as it was already updated to the latest version.
I have two questions.

Is this normal for header files to not have defined flags and we can execute programs with or without them?
Can I completely replace the file I found in google(ipc.h) in my system? Does it work or will I be facing any issues in the future?

My ipc.h file contents the following.
/* Copyright (C) 1995-2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

#ifndef _SYS_IPC_H

#define _SYS_IPC_H  1

#include <features.h>

/* Get system dependent definition of `struct ipc_perm' and more.  */
#include <bits/ipctypes.h>
#include <bits/ipc.h>

#ifndef __uid_t_defined

typedef __uid_t uid_t;

#define __uid_t_defined

#endif

#ifndef __gid_t_defined

typedef __gid_t gid_t;

#define __gid_t_defined

#endif

#ifndef __mode_t_defined

typedef __mode_t mode_t;

#define __mode_t_defined

#endif

#ifndef __key_t_defined

typedef __key_t key_t;

#define __key_t_defined

#endif

__BEGIN_DECLS

/* Generates key for System V style IPC.  */
extern key_t ftok (const char *__pathname, int __proj_id) __THROW;

__END_DECLS

#endif /* sys/ipc.h */

In the above lines you can see that no flags or structures have been defined.

Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use [code block]s to format

As there is no Ubuntu version info in this question please explain what this has to do with Ubuntu. If there is a version of Ubuntu involved please edit the question and add that info.



Is this normal for header files to not have defined flags and we can execute programs with or without them?


Header files are not involved in the execution of programs - only during their compilation.


Can I completely replace the file I found in google(ipc.h) in my system? Does it work or will I be facing any issues in the future?


There should be no need to replace anything - the definitions that you are looking for are not actually missing, they are contained in the #include'd <bits/ipc.h> file. You can check that either by grepping that file, or by running gcc with options -E (to stop after preprocessing) and -dM (to generate a list of #defines)1:
$ echo '#include <sys/ipc.h>' | gcc -dM -E - | grep IPC_
#define IPC_CREAT 01000
#define IPC_STAT 2
#define IPC_EXCL 02000
#define _SYS_IPC_H 1
#define IPC_PRIVATE ((__key_t) 0)
#define IPC_NOWAIT 04000
#define IPC_SET 1
#define IPC_RMID 0

AFAIK both <sys/ipc.h> and <bits/ipc.h> are userland headers provided by the libc6-dev package for your architecture, rather than kernel headers provided by any linux-headers package. You shouldn't be including the latter in a userland program anyhow.


see for example GCC dump preprocessor defines


thank you so much for this explanation! $ echo '#include <sys/ipc.h>' | gcc -dM -E - | grep IPC_ this shows the proof for IPC_ flags existence and other #define list too. Also had some idea of userland (userspace) and kernel land (kernel space) executions. This is new to me, again thanks for educating me on this.
